# Azure-DevOps: Automatic increment docker tag in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, docker-build

```
steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    containerRegistry: myAcrServiceConnection
    repository: roket
    tags: |
      02
      latest
```

The above snippet build an image with tag 02 and tag latest from the same source and push it to the azure container registry.

How can I replace the 02 in the tags to an automatic increment style. For example it will fist fetch the remote or local catch and increment 1 to the tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define the build number in a way that is going to strictly increment (for instance `$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.rr)`), and use `$(Build.BuildNumber)` as a tag for the image.

From [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/run-number?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#tokens):

> Use $(Rev:r) to ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.